# Ruby: Increase time before timeout?

Tags: ruby, timeout

I'm trying to do the following:

```
remote_feed = open(url)
```

But the remote feed takes a while to return, and the call times out.  I just need to increase the time until timeout occurs, is there a simple way to do this in ruby?

Thanks!

Comment: what gem or library are you using for this?

Comment: Apparently I am using 'open-uri' (this is someone else's code who left recently, just discovered this).

Comment: gotcha. I was looking at remote_feed instead of open(url) and was getting confused. I guess I shouldn't browse SO 20 minutes after waking up.

Comment: What version of Ruby are you using? SizzlePants answer is for Ruby 1.9.2+

Comment: Yes, I am using Ruby 1.8.7.  His answer does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'open-uri'

open('http://stackoverflow.com', 'r', :read_timeout=>0.01) do |http|
  http.read
end
```

Comment: or just `open('http://stackoverflow.com', :read_timeout=>0.01).read` `:read_timeout=>nil` if you don't want to use timeout at all

Comment: You might want to teach the OP to fish by pointing him to the docs.

Comment: I am getting the error - bad URI(is not URI?) for a URI of the form:  http://www.clientdomain.com/dw/Connect.asmx/Connect

Comment: A URI must begin with the protocol, i.e., whether it's HTTP, HTTPS, FTP, etc. That's how Open::URI knows what to use when connecting.

Comment: Stackoverflow conveniently turned it into a link.. the original has the http:// on it.

Comment: What are the units on the :read_timeout parameter?  seconds or minutes?  the documentation seems to indicate that they are seconds (http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/OpenURI/OpenRead.html#method-i-open)